# Hibernate - clearing a collection with all-delete-orphan and then adding to it causes ConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate, unique-constraint

I have these entities

```
class Foo{
    Set<Bar> bars;
}

class Bar{
    Foo parent;
    String localIdentifier;
}
```

With this mapping (sorry, no annotations, I'm old fashioned):

```
<class name="Foo">
    ...
    <set name="bars" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" inverse="true">
        <key>...</key>
        <one-to-many class="Bar"/>
    </set>
</class>


<class name="Bar">
    ...
    <property name="localIdentifier" column="local_identifier"/>
    <many-to-one name="parent" column="parent_id" />
</class>
```

I also have a unique constraint on 2 columns: `local_identifier` and `parent_id` (not a unique constrain on each, but a single unique constrain containing both, e.g. no 2 rows with the same parent and same localIdentifier are allowed)

```
alter table bar add constraint unique_bar unique (parent_id, local_identifier)
```

And this code that uses them:

```
//foo is persistent, foo id = 1
Bars bars = foo.getBars();
bars.clear(); // bars contained 1 item [parent_id = 1, local_identifier = "a"]
Bar newBar = new Bar();
newBar.setParent(foo);
newBar.setLocalIdentifier("a");
bars.add(newBar);
```

Now, for some reason, Hibernate doesn't execute things in the order they were called. It doesn't execute the `clear()` (delete) before the `add()` (insert) but vice versa, it first tries to insert, getting a `ConstraintViolationException`

I know adding a little `session.flush()` after `bars.clear();` , could fix this, but in this case, I have no access to the session in a non ugly way.

So is flush is the only solution? or is there a Hibernate version that respects the order of actions?

**Update:**
By the way, dereferencing the collection will result in a HibernateException from https://www.hibernate.org/117.html#A3:

> **I get HibernateException: Don't
>   dereference a collection with
>   cascade="all-delete-orphan"** This
>   will happen if you load an object with
>   a cascade="all-delete-orphan"
>   collection and then remove the
>   reference to the collection. Don't
>   replace this collection, use clear()
>   so the orphan-deletion algorithm can
>   detect your change.

Comment: I think flushing is the only option here

Comment: Relative [Hibernate Forum topic](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=934483).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess there is no alternative to flushing

From [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems?_sscc=t#jive_content_id_Hibernate_is_violating_a_unique_constraint):

> **Hibernate is violating a unique constraint!**
>
> Hibernate isn't quite as
>   clever with unique constraints as it
>   is with foreign keys. Sometimes you
>   might need to give a little hint.
>
> A unique constraint violation could
>   occur if two objects are both being
>   updated, one is "releasing" a value
>   and the other is "obtaining" the same
>   value. A workaround is to **flush()** the
>   session manually after updating the
>   first object and before updating the
>   second.
>
> (This kind of problem occurs rarely in
>   practice.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid flushing the session here, try to replace the whole list (`new List<Bar>()` instead of `Clear()`). Hibernate should actually remove all the items in one shot before adding new. Just a try, not sure if it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using oracle, you could also use deferrable constraints to postpone the checking of the constraints until the transaction is committed. Not sure if/how this is supported by other databases.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly similar issue, where I had a unique index on the child table on certain condition. So my issue was when I remove a record that satisfied this condition, then add another record that will restore that condition back, I got the UNIQUE INDEX issue.

After going through many trials and suggestions. I didn't like the idea of flushing after deleting and before the adding, I assume it will work though, I went to a constraint solution and dropped the unique index (as I didn't really needed the columns to be indexed) which did work:

(On postgres database)

```
ALTER TABLE bar ADD CONSTRAINT bar_uc
        EXCLUDE (parent_id WITH =) WHERE (condition = true) INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

INITIALLY DEFERRED is the key here.

Sample code that I was using:

```
//Transaction 1
Foo parent = new Foo('some-id');
boolean condition = true;
Bar c = new Bar('some-id', parent, condition);
parent.getChildren().add(c);
fooService.save(parent);    //children list are cascaded
```

... later on

```
//Transaction 2
boolean condition = true;
Foo parent = fooSerice.findById('some-id');    //children list is eagerly fetched
Bar c1 = parent.getChildren().stream().filter(c -> c.getId().equals("some-id")).findFirst().get();
Bar c2 = new Bar('some-id1', parent, condition);
parent.getChildren().remove(c1);
parent.getChildren().add(c2);
```