# Unique constraint violation with ordered Hibernate list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, unique-constraint

I have the following entities and get an exception if I try to remove a `Task` from the `TaskList` via `removeTask` method.

```
@Entity
public class TaskList extends GenericModel {

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
  @OrderColumn(name="position", nullable=false)
  public List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

  // ...

  public void removeTask(Task task) {
    tasks.remove(task);
  }
}

@Entity
public class Task extends Model {

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="task_id")
  private List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<>();

  @ManyToOne
  public TaskList taskList;

  // ...
}

@Entity
public class Reservation extends GenericModel {

  @Id
  private String id = Token.generate(8);

  @ManyToOne
  private Task task;

  // ...
}
```

The exception is:

```
"CONSTRAINT_INDEX_F ON PUBLIC.TASKLIST_TASK(TASKS_ID)"
Unique index or primary key violation: "CONSTRAINT_INDEX_F ON PUBLIC.TASKLIST_TASK(TASKS_ID)"; SQL statement:
update TaskList_Task set tasks_id=? where TaskList_id=? and position=? [23001-149]
```

I'm using JPA 2 with Hibernate 3.6.1. Is something wrong with my mapping or is it a Hibernate bug?

UPDATE

It seems to be a Hibernate problem. Something with the order of `delete` and `update` statements. The following hack solved the problem (partly):

```
@Entity
public class TaskList extends GenericModel {

  // ....

  public void removeTask(Task task) {
    tasks.remove(task);
    tasks = new ArrayList<>(tasks); // only for Hibernate
    task.taskList = null;
  }
}
```

[Hibernate - clearing a collection with all-delete-orphan and then adding to it causes ConstraintViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065254/) lead my in the right direction.

*But* `orphanRemoval=true` doesn't work with my workaround. It leads to the next exception: "A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance". So the problem is not really solved.

Comment: Great, the hack worked for me! My scenario was the following one: I removed the first element from a list and then I appended the element at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your bidirectional association is mapped twice: once in TaskList, and once in Task. The mapping annotations in TaskList should be

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="task") 
@OrderColumn(name="position", nullable=false)
public List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

Without the mappedBy attribute, Hibernate considers that you have two separate associations (and I doubt that's what you want), rather than a bidirectional one.

Moreover, when you modify a bidirectional association, both sides of the association should be modified. So the removeTask method should be

```
public void removeTask(Task task) {
    tasks.remove(task);
    task.setTaskList(null);
}
```

That's particularly important, because the owning side of the association is `Task` (because that's where ther is no `mappedBy` attribute). So this is the side that Hibernate inspects to know that the association must be removed.

Comment: `mappedBy` cannot be used together with `@OrderColumn`, because Hibernate consider it to be a bad practice and needs a join table instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956171/ I tried to remove the references as suggested, but it didn't solve the problem.